# How are Associative Arrays (Objects) mapped in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

Do objects in javascript use a Hash Map?
For example when I use

```
var a = {};
a["apple"] = "red";
a["banana"] = "yellow";
...
...
```

How does javascript assign the keys "apple" and "banana" to a position at the memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under the hood, are Javascript objects hash tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256974/under-the-hood-are-javascript-objects-hash-tables)

Comment: Afaik that's not specified by the ECMAScript standard and therefore browser dependant. What's your actual question? Why did you ask *this* question?