# Best way to filter the array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with a property I want to filter on called "Country". I have the user select which countries they want to see and wish to return an array of objects filtered by that property. What is the most efficient way to complete this process?

```
  var countries = [{GINI: 56.2, Country: "Central African Republic", Values: Array, Date: "2008"},
  {GINI: 51.3, Country: "Brazil", Values: Array, Date: "2015"},{GINI: 51.1, Country: "Columbia", Values: Array, Date: "2015"}]


 var selectedCountries = ["Central African Republic", "Columbia"];

 var filteredCountries = countries.filter(country =>{

  ??  
 });
```

Output should be a filtered version of the countries array containing the matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const countries = [{GINI: 56.2, Country: "Central African Republic", Values: Array, Date: "2008"},{GINI: 51.3, Country: "Brazil", Values: Array, Date: "2015"},{GINI: 51.1, Country: "Columbia", Values: Array, Date: "2015"}]
const selectedCountries = ["Central African Republic", "Columbia"];

const filteredCountries = countries.filter(({Country})=>selectedCountries.includes(Country));

console.log(filteredCountries)
```

I will prefer to have `selectedCountries` as an `Object` instead of an `Array`. Than need not to loop on Array every time.

```js
const countries = [{GINI: 56.2, Country: "Central African Republic", Values: Array, Date: "2008"},{GINI: 51.3, Country: "Brazil", Values: Array, Date: "2015"},{GINI: 51.1, Country: "Columbia", Values: Array, Date: "2015"}]

const selectedCountries = {
 "Central African Republic": true,
 "Columbia": true
};

const filteredCountries = countries.filter(({Country})=>selectedCountries[Country]);

console.log(filteredCountries)
```

Comment: I din't understand the idea behind using `selectedCountries` as object

Comment: @ShubhDixit than you can directly access value based on key. it will have time complexity of `O(1)` while on array it will be `O(n)`

Comment: Just for the record ,how will it be O(1) ,if you can throw some light?

Comment: @ShubhDixit JS objects uses hashes you can read this answer this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266944/complexity-of-accessing-data-in-an-object

Answer (score 0):

You can use check if the Country of the object is in `selectedCountries` using **[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)**

```js
var countries = [{
    GINI: 56.2,
    Country: "Central African Republic",
    Values: Array,
    Date: "2008"
  },
  {
    GINI: 51.3,
    Country: "Brazil",
    Values: Array,
    Date: "2015"
  }, {
    GINI: 51.1,
    Country: "Columbia",
    Values: Array,
    Date: "2015"
  }
]
var selectedCountries = ["Central African Republic", "Columbia"];
const filteredCountries = countries.filter(count => selectedCountries.includes(count.Country))
console.log(filteredCountries)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) by `Country` (O(n)) using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the list of requested countries (O(m)), and get the country from the Map. The complexity would be O(n + m).

```js
const countries = [{GINI: 56.2, Country: "Central African Republic", Values: [], Date: "2008"}, {GINI: 51.3, Country: "Brazil", Values: Array, Date: "2015"},{GINI: 51.1, Country: "Columbia", Values: [], Date: "2015"}];

const selectedCountries = ["Central African Republic", "Columbia"];

const countryMap = countries.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.Country, o), new Map);

const filteredCountries = selectedCountries.map(c => countryMap.get(c));

console.log(filteredCountries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use of array.indexOf function

```js
 var countries = [{GINI: 56.2, Country: "Central African Republic", Values: Array, Date: "2008"},
  {GINI: 51.3, Country: "Brazil", Values: Array, Date: "2015"},{GINI: 51.1, Country: "Columbia", Values: Array, Date: "2015"}]


 var selectedCountries = ["Central African Republic", "Columbia"];

 var filteredCountries = countries.filter(country =>selectedCountries.indexOf(country.Country)!=-1);
 console.log(filteredCountries)
```