# Object complexity while search by key

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I have the following object:

```
let obj = {
  "name": "someName",
  "age": 33,
  "city": "someCity"
}
```

I understand that an object is not indexed

> "JS objects have no defined order, they are (by definition) an
> unsorted set of key-value pairs."

so what is the complexity of:

```
let result = obj.name
```

Is it searching all over the object to find the right key?
Is there a way to index this object so complexity will be O(1)?

Comment: I'm 99% sure that, unless JS has some weird quirk, the complexity is O(1), and that it doesn't search because it uses a hash table. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

Data access which involves retrieving or modifying data stored in an object is done in constant time `O(1)`. This is also true for the insertion and removal of data.

Comment: May I suggest that you provide a citation for this?  And maybe explain that this is because  objects in JS are backed by hashtables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266944/complexity-of-accessing-data-in-an-object