# How find first array of objects id in second array of object and assign second array of object in new object (Problem is that i have two array data )?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

1. Problem is that i have two array data and MfaData.
2. if data.mfaserviceid same as mfaData.id then assign  mfa_name to this array of object.

```
const mfaData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    mfa_name: "PASSWORD",
    isActive: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    mfa_name: "PIN",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    mfa_name: "GRID",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    mfa_name: "PASSCODE",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    mfa_name: "QUESTION",
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    id: 18,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "3",
  },
  {
    id: 19,

    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "2",
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "1",
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "1",
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "2",
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "3",
  },
  {
    id: 24,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "4",
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "5",
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "1",
  },
  {
    id: 27,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "2",
  },
  {
    id: 28,

    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "3",
  },
  {
    id: 29,

    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "4",
  },
  {
    id: 30,

    channelname: "POS",
    mfaserviceid: "5",
  },
  {
    id: 31,
    channelname: "UPI",
    mfaserviceid: "1",
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    channelname: "UPI",
    mfaserviceid: "2",
  },
];
```

logic i implementd but not working

```
const mergedRes = data.map((item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, mfaData[i]));
```

the result i want in this way

```
const mergedRes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfa_name: "PASSWORD", // this is from mfaData
    mfaserviceid: "3",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    channelname: "POS",
    mfa_name: "PASSWORD", // here i want to get mfa_name from mfaData
    mfaserviceid: "3",
  },
];
```

///
Problem is that i have two array data and MfaData.
if data.mfaserviceid same as mfaData.id then assign mfa_name to this array of object.
////
///
Problem is that i have two array data and MfaData.
if data.mfaserviceid same as mfaData.id then assign mfa_name to this array of object.
///

Comment: also [how to merge two arrays of objects in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048528/how-to-merge-two-arrays-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: *"if data.mfaserviceid same as mfaData.id then assign mfa_name to this array of object."* Why does the result have `id: 1` and `mfaserviceid:"3"`? Not only do they not match as numbers, they don't match types as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < mfaData.length ; i++){
    
    for(let j = 0 ; j < data.length ;j++ ){
        if(+data[j].mfaserviceid === mfaData[i].id){
            data[j].mfa_name = mfaData[i].mfa_name
        }
    }
    
}
console.log(data)
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

What your asking is if `data.mfaserviceid` === `mfaData.id` then merge the mfa_name with the object from data. This cannot be done in a single map I do not think.

```
const mergedArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < mfaData.length; i++) {
  const mfaElement = mfaData[i];

  for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    const dataElement = data[j];

    if (parseInt(dataElement.mfaserviceid) === mfaElement.id) {
      mergedArray.push({ mfa_name: mfaElement.mfa_name, ...dataElement });
    }
  }
}
```

This is the slow way, I do not know what your non-functional requirements are. This loops through both arrays. mfaserviceid is a string so you have to cast it to a number and compare it to mfaElement.id. If they are equal, then we can use ES 6 spread operator to merge mfa_name with the existing object from data.