# How does JavaScript object property retrieval work behind the scenes?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'David',
  lastName: 'Ferrera',
  age: 30,
};
```

and I want to access two properties:

- `person['lastName']`
- `person['lastname']`

**How does this work behind the scenes?**

Comment: This is not a search it is the accessing of an object property. And what do you mean with "behind the scene"? Do you want assembly code or what?

Comment: related if one is interested in _engine_-implementation details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6586670/11107541

Comment: see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 2):

The engine looks at the object itself and checks whether it has the property or not. If yes, it returns the corresponding value. If not, it gets the object's prototype (which is just an object as well) and repeats the process. It does that until the property is either found or the currently inspected object doesn't have a prototype. In the last case it returns `undefined`.

This is all defined in the spec in [9.1.8.1 OrdinaryGet ( O, P, Receiver )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ordinaryget).

Since `lastName` exists in `person`, the property is found and `"Ferrera"` is returned.

Since `lastname` does not exist in `person`, the engine continues to look at its prototype (`Object.getPrototypeOf(person)`). Since it doesn't have `lastname` and it doesn't have a prototype either, `undefined` is returned.