# What type of operation occurs with the syntax object["key String"] JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I would like to know more about the internal workings of JavaScript to better understand what is happening.

With the following object

```
let test = {"A": 10,"D" : 6, "PP" : 777};

console.log (test["PP"]): // 777

console.log (test.PP): // 777
```

How does JavaScript find my value with potential N element in the object?

My question is about the inner workings.

Imagine an object with 100,000 properties how will it find the key "PP" what job will it do? How does JS work to give us the value 777?

Comment: There are two ways to access object properties: the `[ ]` operator, and (for properties whose names are suitable) the `.` operator. Both do the same thing.

Comment: "how he find": is your question about how JavaScript stores objects? Or about the syntax to retrieve a value? Or...?

Comment: My English is not very good, my question is about the inner workings.

Imagine an object with 100,000 properties how will it find the key "PP" what job will it do ? how  JS work for to give us the value 777 ?

Comment: Is that *really* what you want to know? Well, okay…  https://stackoverflow.com/q/6586670/476

Comment: thx you  ,exactly